# Lookahead inside or clause failing in textx

Tags: python, textx

The following throws an exception for me (on line 9), complaining that `Expected '.' at position (5, 15) => 'k foo bar *end '.`:

```
mm = metamodel_from_str('''
File: Line*;
Line: Block | Sentence;
Sentence: 'foo' 'bar' ( '.' | &'end' );
Block: 'block' Line* 'end';
''', skipws=True)
program = mm.model_from_str('''\
foo bar .
block
    foo bar .
end
block foo bar end
''')
```

However, it parses successfully if I write what I think is an equivalent grammar:

```
File: Line*;
Line: Block | InnerSentence | Sentence;
Sentence: 'foo' 'bar' '.';
InnerSentence: 'foo' 'bar' &'end';
Block: 'block' Line* 'end';
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positive lookahead tries to match the given input and succeeds if the match succeeds but it never consumes the input. It is meant to be used as a part of the sequence to continue matching subsequent elements of the sequence *only* if the expression given to lookahead can be matched. It is not very useful on its own.

In the rule `Sentence: 'foo' 'bar' ( '.' | &'end' );` the ordered choice at the end would try to match `.` and after that lookahead `end` would succeed but there is nothing to match in that sequence, the match is empty and that branch of ordered choice fails. To overcome the issue you can change your rule to be:

```
Sentence: 'foo' 'bar' ( '.' | &'end' '');
```

Now you have an explicit empty string match after the lookahead which provides the result of the ordered choice alternative.

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining this! I'd still be inclined to say that the behaviour forced by the '' should be the default (why would you ever want to fail that match?), but at least I can easily workaround it. Is it worth creating a PR for the docs to warn people about this, as I don't believe it's documented?

Comment: Yes, please do create an issue about this. We should probably first discuss there should we change the behavior of lookaheads or improve the docs.